# JNI methods modifying pointers

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Having a peculiar problem. When I call the following JNI method.

```
jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(list->size, jclass, 0);
```

Now, `list->size` is set to 54. But as soon as the code above is run the same pointer returns, `2405015736` whats going on? As affects the values held in the rest of the struct also. Setting a static value i.e.

```
jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(54, jclass, 0)
```

Also has no effect. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

(jclass is a loaded class object `jclass = env->FindClass("name");` )

Thanks

Comment: The same pointer? What do you mean by this? Also, use jclass instead of proc_jclass.

Comment: By "why is interfering with everything in the list struct" do you mean that `list->size` is 54 *before* `jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(list->size, jclass, 0)`, but then `list->size` is `2405015736` *after*? If so, I think that you need to post the type of `list`, how you allocated space for `*list`, and how you initialized `*list`. It almost seems that `list` is a pointer into the stack, which can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: It is created     list_struct *list; and then     list_create(list); is called to take in that list pointer and make changes to the struct.

Comment: What is the function signature of `list_create`?

Comment: JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_example_JNI_nList(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)

Comment: I mean, in your C++ file where you have the line `jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(list->size, jclass, 0)`, how *exactly* is `list` declared and initialized before that line is reached? Either it is a local object, or you allocate heap memory somehow. I'm looking for the "somehow", or if it is a local object, what its *exact* type is. Please edit your question to include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that size may not be of 'jsize' type so conversion has to take place. Now, this would be all well and good, but JNI is an absolute pain with this stuff. I think what is happening is that your stack is getting corrupted from a number which is interpreted as being too big. Or something like that. Just do the size conversion like so:

```
jint msize = list->size;
jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(msize, jclass, 0);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thats interesting it worked, but why is interfering with everything in the list struct?

Comment: Stack corruption :) The size variable problem was causing the allocation to eat up all available memory, I believe. If it worked, accept as answer please! :D

Also, if you return a number from a function, make sure you do something similar and use an intermediary holder first! JNI is such a pain :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not too sure why it works, maybe its not stack corruption. Perhaps other people can shed more light on the problem? Maybe it's heap corruption instead with a dodgy pointer.